# How to show data on EJS Template

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb query formatted as follows:

```
db.cdrs.aggreagate([


{
        "$match": {
            "$and":[
                {"date": "2019-07-24"},
                {"source": /2^/}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": 
            {
                "cvtDuration": {"$toInt": "$duration"},
                "cvtBillsec": {"$toInt": "$billsec"}
            }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "destination": "$source",
                "disposition": "$disposition"
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            },
            "duration": {
                "$sum": "$ctvDuration"
            },
            "billsec":{
                "$sum": "$cvtBillsec"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.destination",
            "Test": {
                "$push": {
                    "disposition": "$_id.disposition",
                    "count": "$count",
                    "duration": "$duration",
                    "billsec": "$billsec"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output Data:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "100",
        "Test": [
            {
                "disposition": "ANSWERED",
                "count": 4,
                "duration": 444,
                "billsec": 419
            },
            {
                "disposition": "BUSY",
                "count": 3,
                "duration": 28,
                "billsec": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "101",
        "Test": [
            {
                "disposition": "Busy",
                "count": 4,
                "duration": 25,
                "billsec": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to transfer  output data into a table via ejs with format:

```
extension | Answered Call | Busy Call | Fail Call | Duration | Billsec
100       |      4        |     3     |     0     |    444   |   419
101       |      0        |     4     |     0     |     0        0
```

I used two for loops:

```
<%for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++){%>
     <tr>
         <td><%=data.results[i]._id%></td>
         <%for(var j = 0; j < data.results[i].Test.length; j++){%>
              <td><%=data.results[i].Test[j].count%></td>
              <td><%=data.results[i].Test[j].duration%></td><td>    
              <%=data.results[i].Test[j].billsec%></td>                      
         <%}%>
     </tr>  
<%}%>
```

Output:

```
extension | Answered Call | Busy Call | Fail Call | Duration | Billsec
100       |      4        |     444   |     419   |    3     |   28
101       |      4        |     25     |     0    |          |    0
```

How do i have output as required?

Comment: The algorithm you wrote simply doesn't work in the way you intend. Objects in `Test` arrays are displayed in the columns by their type (e.g. the number of *answered* calls). If the order of `Test` arrays isn't guaranteed, and it is not in your case, you can't simply iterate over them and expect that the values will magically end up in correct positions. You need to either redesign your database scheme or rewrite the inner for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This ejs works correctly.

```
<style>
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
</style>
<table id='table'>
  <tr>
    <th>extension</th>
    <th>Answered Call</th>
    <th>Busy Call</th>
    <th>Fail Call</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
    <th>Billsec</th>
  </tr>
  <%for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++){%>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%=data.results[i]._id%>
      </td>

      <td onclick="loadData(this,<%=JSON.stringify(data.results[i].Test)%>,'count','ANSWERED');"></td>
      <td onclick="loadData(this,<%=JSON.stringify(data.results[i].Test)%>,'count','BUSY')"></td>
      <td onclick="loadData(this,<%=JSON.stringify(data.results[i].Test)%>,'count','FAILED')"></td>
      <td onclick="loadData(this,<%=JSON.stringify(data.results[i].Test)%>,'duration','ANSWERED')"></td>
      <td onclick="loadData(this,<%=JSON.stringify(data.results[i].Test)%>,'billsec','ANSWERED')"></td>

    </tr>
    <%}%>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table tr td').click();
  });

  function loadData(td, result, key, check) {
    //  console.log(td);
    var val = 0;
    result.forEach(el => {

      console.log(el.disposition.toUpperCase(), check, el[key]);
      if (el.disposition.toUpperCase() == check)
        val = el[key];

    });
    td.innerHTML = val;
  }
</script>
```